# PHP if statement not returning the right page number

Tags: php, if-statement

Ive got this script to narrow down which page number a release ID is it seems to work for the most part but when i enter 0013 as the number it should say its pageNum=311 but it always comes back with 261.

Have i done something wrong?

**Here is the script:**

```
$releaseNumber = sprintf('%04d', 0013);

if($releaseNumber < 6300 && $releaseNumber > 6000) {
    $pageNum = 1;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 6001 && $releaseNumber > 5800) {
    $pageNum = 16;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 5801 && $releaseNumber > 5600) {
    $pageNum = 26;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 5601 && $releaseNumber > 5200) {
    $pageNum = 36;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 5201 && $releaseNumber > 5000) {
    $pageNum = 56;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 5001 && $releaseNumber > 4700) {
    $pageNum = 66;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 4701 && $releaseNumber > 4300) {
    $pageNum = 81;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 4301 && $releaseNumber > 3900) {
    $pageNum = 101;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 3901 && $releaseNumber > 3500) {
    $pageNum = 121;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 3501 && $releaseNumber > 3100) {
    $pageNum = 141;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 3101 && $releaseNumber > 2700) {
    $pageNum = 161;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 2701 && $releaseNumber > 2300) {
    $pageNum = 181;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 2301 && $releaseNumber > 1900) {
    $pageNum = 201;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 1901 && $releaseNumber > 1500) {
    $pageNum = 221;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 1501 && $releaseNumber > 1100) {
    $pageNum = 241;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 1101 && $releaseNumber > 0900) {
    $pageNum = 261;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 0901 && $releaseNumber > 0700) {
    $pageNum = 271;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 0701 && $releaseNumber > 0500) {
    $pageNum = 281;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 0501 && $releaseNumber > 0301) {
    $pageNum = 291;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 0301 && $releaseNumber > 0100) {
    $pageNum = 301;
}elseif($releaseNumber < 0101 && $releaseNumber > 0000) {
    $pageNum = 311;
}
```

Comment: Integers don't use prefixed zeros and if you try to use prefixed zeros then it converts it to an octal value. `$releaseNumber < 101 && $releaseNumber > 0` or `$releaseNumber < '0101' && $releaseNumber > '0000'`

Comment: Also, just for sake of helping your code look better/be easier to read, you don't need to check if `$releaseNumber < number` in your elseif statements because if `$releaseNumber were > number` it would have fallen into the if/elseif statement above.

Comment: @Almado My script works just didn't know about Octal, Not sure how i need to debug that? and i only code for myself so why do i need to learn arrays or switch-case, If it works im happy.

Comment: *" Not sure how i need to debug that?"* - Well by checking what your program does and if that number is the number you expect. So you take your finding of dissent between your expectation and what the code actually does and you use debugging to find out why the expectation differs with the code (and where for the first time).

Comment: i already know what it does, It was stopping early because i didn't know that by having leading zeros it turned it into a different number, would debugging tell me that?

Comment: Well normally it does because for debugging you introduce variables and you output them. Like [`$number = 0013; var_dump($number);`](http://3v4l.org/N65KQ). Or more comfortable with a step-debugger, e.g. Xdebug.

Comment: ok fair enough, Will check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number starting with a 0 is interpreted as a base 8 number, or octal notation.

See [octal notations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero). To use hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize. Its working now.

Comment: As someone else mentioned it, you probably could improve your code by creating an array that maps release numbers to page numbers.

Comment: How would it improve it? Would an array make it run quicker? it does the job at the moment to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

PHP reads number as octal number (not Ocelet!) when you put 0 in front. 
0013 would become 11 so it definitely would be at page 261

Comment: The Ocelet  (note the big O at the beginning), is a very rare and shy animal of the northern hemisphere.

Comment: Thank you! I must have one of those Ocelet sitting in the backyard..

Comment: Pssst: The Ocelet doesn't exist as well, it's the Ocelot :D And that's a really cute one.